# Is it possible to use training, validation and test split for regression models?

Tags: regression, time-series, validation, lstm

For classification problems, we can split the data into training, validation and test sets. And we can use the validation set for obtaining an unbiased estimation of the loss of our model. We can monitor the validation loss (or accuracy) in early stoping for stoping the training when the model is not improving on the validation.

Is it possible to do something similar to this when working with time series forecasting with LSTM? How can we do that?

Is it possible to use early stoping with some custom function for evaluating the performance of our model? For example, let ut suppose that we would like to use RMSE on validation set during the training of our LSTM. Is it possible to do that?

Best regards.

Comment: Are you asking about regression models or time-series data? Those are orthogonal things. Early stopping seems to be a separate issue. Could you edit to clarify?

Comment: For time series, you can split off a test set as the most recent data, allowing you to train and validate on the earlier data.  You need to split off at least as much for testing as the period you want to forecast forward, and possibly more.  With what is left, for validation you can do something similar, splitting off more recent data for validation (possibly several different splits) and training using even earlier data.  This may require more data than conventional  training/validation/testing on non-time-series data. You cannot apply the random selection you might otherwise have done

Comment: The regression vs classification issue is separate from the time series issue.